# how to create a SimpleListFilter in django

Tags: django, filter, admin

I don't succeed to write a query filter.
I have 3 models: Patient, Prescription and User

I write you only what is relevant for my question

Patient:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(
   settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Prescription:

```
class Prescription(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(
          User,
          null=True,
          blank=False,
          on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
         )
         file_extention = models.CharField(
         'file extention',
         max_length=8,
         null=True,
         blank=True,
         )
```

So the relation between both of models (Patient and Prescription) are through User.

in the PatientAdmin, I want to filter on the file_extension according pdf or jpg of the prescription uploaded.
I created a SimpleListFilter but impossible to find the right query.

```
class PrescriptionFileExtensionFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    """This filter is being used in django admin panel in 
    patient model."""
    title = 'Prescription File Ext'
    parameter_name = 'file_extention'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
       return (
               ('pdf', 'PDF'),
               ('jpg', 'JPG'),
              )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
       for user in queryset:
           if self.value() == 'pdf':
              return queryset.filter(user=user.user).filter
                     (prescription__file_extention="pdf")

           if self.value() == 'jpg':
              return queryset.filter(user=user.user).filter 
                     (prescription__file_extention="jpg")
```

That's not working...
Do I need the for user in queryset:
need What could be the query to bring me all the users with a prescription with file_extension = "pdf" (or "jpg")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a key from the prescription object in `print(mydict['file_extention'])` which I believe is causing the issue - you would instead access that property via `mydict.file_extention` - though I should add that mydict is not an accurate variable name for a model object as it isn't a dictionary. I don't think that for loop is actually doing anything other than printing a particular value so it can be removed altogether.

As an aside, you have two filters on your queryset, this can just be expressed as a single filter, separate by a comma, e.g.

```
return queryset.filter(user=user.user, prescription__file_extention="pdf")
```

You are also calling `user.user`, presumably you just want to get the user model which is kept in `request.user` - is that what your for loop was trying to do?

**Edit**

If you want to get **all** of the users but just filtered by JPG or PDF then you need to remove two things:

1. The for-loop of `for user in queryset`
2. The filter of `.filter(user=user.user)`

The for loop is unnecessary in the queryset function and the filter is just getting a single user, but you want to get all of them - correct?

Comment: thanks for your answer but you miss the point i think because maybe my explanation in the question.
mydict.file_extention is not working - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_extention'
mydict is just for test to find how to reach the file_extension value
request.user is not the right user. user.user is the user attribute of the patient model that is correct. 
what i want is to filter all the user that has a prescription with a file pdf or jpg

Comment: I've updated my answers - assuming you want to get all of the users then remove the loop and filter

Comment: it's not working because prescription is not a field of Patient. that's the reason why i need to go through user.

Comment: Are you trying to get a queryset of patients or prescriptions?

Comment: i'm trying to get a queryset of patient that have a prescription of type pdf (or jpg)

Comment: try this `return queryset.filter(user__prescription__file_extention="pdf")`

Comment: it's working. you're the best man. can I ask you also to explain why is it that?
and is it right to make something like this also to implement the OR logic:
return queryset.filter(user__prescription__file_extention="pdf" | user__prescription__file_extention="jpg" )

Comment: It works because the queryset already has exist to user, and prescription is connected to the user - it's just a matter of using the double underscore notation to access it through the model accessors. If you want OR logic then you can use a Q() object to connect them